# WebAPP Quiz html - read data from google spreadsheet - select sheet

Tags: html, web-applications, spreadsheet

What I am trying is to have a little web app published that has a selector to choose one of the sheets in a spreadsheet.

Then, fetch the data in that sheet to build a Quiz.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!-- Build select options from spreadsheet sheets -->
<?  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_key'); ?>
  <select id="select_sheet" onchange="showQuestion(this.value);">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Choose unit</option>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < ss.getSheets().length; ++i) { ?>
      <option><?!= ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() ?></option>
    <? } ?>
  </select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>       
function showQuestion(name){

  <? var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_key').getSheetByName(name).getDataRange().getValues; ?>    

    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = <?= data[0][0] ?>;
    document.getElementById("btn0").innerHTML = <?= data[0][1] ?>;
    document.getElementById("btn1").innerHTML = <?= data[0][2] ?>;
    document.getElementById("btn2").innerHTML = <?= data[0][3] ?>;
    document.getElementById("btn3").innerHTML = <?= data[0][4] ?>;
}
</script>
```

The selector menu is built correctly, however, I can't manage to trigger a function onchange that can read the data from the sheet selected (select_sheet)

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your option tag should have value attribute set.

Change:

```
<option><?!= ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() ?></option>
```

to:

```php
<option value="<?= ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() ?>"><?!= ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() ?></option>
```

Comment: OK. Noted, however the code did fine without adding a value to <option> 

this.value had the name of the sheet selected (I did a console.log)

My issue is, how can I access the data stored in the sheet? Any ideas? Thanks for the input though